# count grand total of group by operation but also sub total of the same group by operation based on other columns

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a table called `test` that looks like that:

```
create table test (
    org varchar,
    product varchar,
    release_date varchar,
    date_avail varchar,
    status varchar
);

insert into test values 
    ('a','bpm','2022-07','no','green'),
    ('a','bpm','2022-07','no','green'),
    ('a','bpm','2022-07','no','yellow'),
    ('a','bpm','2022-07','yes','yellow'),
    ('b','ppp','2022-08','no','green'),
    ('b','ppp','2022-08','no','green');
```

I want to group by `org,product,release_date` and get the total count, this is straightforward:

```
select org,product,release_date
,count(1) as total
from test
group by org,product,release_date
;
```

result:

```
"a" "bpm"   "2022-07"   4
"b" "ppp"   "2022-08"   2
```

However I would like also to get sub-count from this group for the different values of the other columns that were not grouped. For example, first group which has `4` as total count is `"a" "bpm"   "2022-07"` . This group has `3` `no` and `1` yes for column `date_avail` and `2` `green` and `2` `yellow` for column `status`.

So my desired table result would look like:

```
org product release_date total number_of_no number_of_yes number_of_green number_of_yellow
a   bpm     2022-07      4     3             1            2               2
b   ppp     2022-08      2     2             0            2               0
```

I use `postgres` version `14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query

```
SELECT org, product, release_date
    , COUNT(1) AS total
    , SUM(CASE WHEN date_avail = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_no
    , SUM(CASE WHEN date_avail = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_yes
    , SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_green
    , SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_yellow  
FROM test
GROUP BY org,product,release_date;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/rL_sD7H-).